# Sending Commands to Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service, command, isolatedstorage

I am trying to send custom commands to a windows service. My application has a windows service and a form. When the service is running I want to create a file in Isolated Storage using a button click event. I am using this tutorial http://arcanecode.com/2007/05/30/windows-services-in-c-sending-commands-to-your-windows-service-part-7/. When I run the program and click the button nothing seems to happen and the file is not place into Isolated Storage. I have put break points on these methods to see if they execute and they seem to work. I am not sure if the button click method can reach the Isolated Storage code in the service from the form but according to this tutorial I cannot see what the problem would be. Source code below.

**Form**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Project2Service;

namespace Project2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Service1 s = new Service1();
        public ServiceInstaller si = new ServiceInstaller();
        public ProjectInstaller pi = new ProjectInstaller();
        public ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Project2Service");

        private string[] isoType;

        string machineName = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            isoType = new string[] { "User", "Assembly And Domain"};
            cboIsoType.Items.AddRange(isoType);

            cboIsoType.SelectedIndex = 0;

            btnContinue.Enabled = false;
            btnPause.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
        }

        public void Labels()
        {
            lblMachine.Text = machineName;
            lblSName.Text = s.ServiceName;
            lblSType.Text = si.StartType.ToString();

            lblSStatus.Text = sc.Status.ToString();
            lblPause.Text = sc.CanPauseAndContinue.ToString();
            lblShutdown.Text = sc.CanShutdown.ToString();
            lblStop.Text = sc.CanStop.ToString();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Controller.Refresh(); //Gets the current status of service
            //if (Controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            //{
            //    Controller.Start();
            //}

            sc.Start();
            sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
            Labels();

            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnContinue.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
            btnPause.Enabled = true;

        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sc.Stop();
            sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
            Labels();

            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnContinue.Enabled = false;
            btnPause.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sc.Pause();
            sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Paused);
            Labels();

            btnPause.Enabled = false;
            btnContinue.Enabled = true;
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sc.Continue();
            sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
            Labels();

            btnStop.Enabled = true;
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnPause.Enabled = true;
            btnContinue.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceController sc2 = new ServiceController("Project2Service");
            sc2.ExecuteCommand(200);

            //if (cboIsoType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "User")   
            //{

            //    sc.ExecuteCommand(128);
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project2Service
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public enum commands
        {
            LogIt = 200
        }

        //public enum ServiceCustomCommands { Command1 = 128, Command2 = 129 };
        //private IsolatedStorageScope iso;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            //iso = IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain;
            FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Project2\ServiceTest");
            Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                        | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                        | NotifyFilters.FileName
                        | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Changed);
            Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Created);
            Watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Deleted);
            Watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(Watcher_Renamed);
            WriteServiceInfo("Service Started!");
        }

        // This event is raised when a file is changed
        private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteServiceInfo("File Changed!");

            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Project2\ServiceTest");//Assuming Watch is your Folder
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Getting Text files
            string str = "";
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                str = str + ", " + file.Name;
                str = str + ", " + file.LastWriteTime;
                str = str + ", " + file.CreationTime;
                str = str + ", " + file.Length;

                WriteServiceInfo(file.Name);
                WriteServiceInfo(file.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                WriteServiceInfo(file.CreationTime.ToString());
                WriteServiceInfo(file.Length.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteServiceInfo("File Created!");
        }

        private void Watcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteServiceInfo("File Deleted!");
        }
        private void Watcher_Renamed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteServiceInfo("File Renamed!");
        }

        private void WriteServiceInfo(string info)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Project2\WindowsServiceLog.txt",
                                 FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
            m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            m_streamWriter.WriteLine(info + "\n");
            m_streamWriter.Flush();
            m_streamWriter.Close();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            WriteServiceInfo("Service Stopped!");

        }

        protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
        {
            base.OnCustomCommand(command);
            if (command == (int)commands.LogIt)
            {
                IsolatedStorageFile isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
                IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("LaptopInfo.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, isoFile);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Data");
                }
            }
        }

        //protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
        //{
        //    switch ((ServiceCustomCommands)command)
        //    {
        //        case ServiceCustomCommands.Command1:
        //            //Command1 Implementation
        //            IsolatedStorageFile isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
        //            IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("LaptopInfo.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, isoFile);
        //            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
        //            {
        //                writer.WriteLine("Data");
        //            }
        //            //iso = IsolatedStorageScope.User;
        //            break;
        //        case ServiceCustomCommands.Command2:
        //            //iso = IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly;
        //            break;
        //        default:
        //            break;

        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already answered this on your other thread, let me look for any new info here

Comment: send me your project adamt at microsoft I'll check it out

Comment: How would I do this @AdamTuliper-MSFT

Comment: right click on your solution, select "Open folder in file explorer". Close visual studio out. Go up one folder (or two) to your folder that contains all your solution stuff and right click in it and send to->comrpessed folder. Email it to me.. but FIRST go into the folder, find your bin/debug folder and delete it for each project. many email filters wont allow .exe files in zips.

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT whats your email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things here:
1. Check the account your service is running as. With your service installer you can specify. I tested your *exact* scenario (using your code) with System to ensure I can access files *on my desktop* as a log test and it worked fine.
2. Limit the test case to not log to isolated, but a simple text file log.

I also posted code that I used to your other post - so lets clean this up first and figure out which one to resolve on.

Comment: I took these two scenarios and implemented them. The account the service is running on is LocalSystem and I took away the isolated storage part and just wrote to a text file `WriteServiceInfo("data written to isolated storage")` and it works. Putting the file into IsolatedStorage is the problem. The custom commands are working.

Comment: Jusy curious, with system permissions and running a service why are you using local storage and not a normal file? Also if you must use isolated storage try running your service as a specific account.